# send values in Node JS Handlebars JS MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I currently have two queries.

```
router.get('/:id_school/:grade', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
  const { id_school, grade } = req.params;
  const { id_enrollment } = req.body;
  const enrollment = await db.query('SELECT * FROM enrollment where enrollment.id_school = ?', [id_school]);

  const subjects = await db.query('SELECT * FROM subjects where id_enrollment = ?', [id_enrollment]);

  console.log(enrollment,subjects);
  res.render('list', {enrollment,subjects});
});
```

The first goes without any problem.

```
const enrollment = await db.query ('SELECT * FROM enrollment where enrollment.id_school =?', [id_school]);
```

But the second query I don't get the results.

```
const subjects = await db.query ('SELECT * FROM subjects where id_enrollment =?', [id_enrollment]);
```

Any idea how I can pass the value in the last part

```
license_id =? ', [id_enrollment]
```

I tried the following, I don't know where I could be wrong.

```
const subjects = await db.query ('SELECT * FROM subjects where id_enrollment =?', + [id_enrollment]);

const subjects = await db.query ('SELECT * FROM subjects where id_enrollment =?', [req.body.id_enrollment]);

const subjects = await db.query ('SELECT * FROM subjects where id_enrollment =?', + req.body.id_enrollment);
```

Comment: Which package are you using for `db.query`? mysql? or any orm?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Is id_enrollment set ? (I mean did you verify if it is null or undefined first ?)

2 - In the first sql you specified the table in where condition 'enrollment.id_school = ?' not in the second 'id_enrollment = ?'

3 - You can maybe try to concat with the id_enrollment value this way:

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM subjects where id_enrollment =' + mysql.escape(id_enrollment))
```

4 - You mentionned license_id but I don't see it in your sql